# NuGet: Get all available Updates for a Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I'm struggling with the nuget-commandline (Nuget 2.8.5 with Visual Studio 2013)
I want to see all packages for a project which have an update (without installing them)
I tried

```
Get-Package -Updates -ProjectName MyProject
```

it doesn't work

> Get-Package : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
>   At line:1 char:12
>   + Get-Package <<<<  -Updates -ProjectName MyProject
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Package], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.GetPackageCommand

I don't get what I'm doing wrong but I assume it's something fairly basic...

EDIT: Sorry, version 2.8.5 is the extension for visual studio's version number

Comment: After some research it seems like a powershell limitation but I still don't understand it 
https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Update-Package -ProjectName MyProject -WhatIf
```

The `-WhatIf` flag means that it won't actually run any updates, it will only show you what *would* happen without doing anything.

See the docs for [Update-Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Update-Package) for more details.

Comment: Thank you
Now have to figure out why nuget seems to ignore the "allowedVersion" in my packages.conf. But I will open another question for that